# Compute $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

> Compute the Fourier series for $x^3$ and use it to compute the value of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$.

I determined the coefficients of the Fourier series, which are

$$a_0 = \dfrac{\pi^3}{2}; \qquad a_n = \dfrac{6(\pi^2 n^2 - 2)(-1)^n + 12}{\pi n^4}$$

Then, I get

$$x^3 = \dfrac{\pi^3}{4} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{6(\pi^2 n^2 - 2)(-1)^n + 12}{\pi n^4}\cos(nx)$$

If $x = \pi$, then

$$\begin{aligned}
\pi^3 &= \dfrac{\pi^3}{4} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{6(\pi^2 n^2 - 2)(-1)^n + 12}{\pi n^4}\cos(n\pi)\\
\dfrac{3\pi^3}{4} &= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{6(\pi^2 n^2 - 2)(-1)^n + 12}{\pi n^4}(-1)^n
\end{aligned}$$

I'm stuck.  It's easy to compute $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$, using the Fourier series, but for this type of problem I'm stuck.

Any comments or suggestions?  By the way, I know that

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4} = \dfrac{\pi^4}{90}$$

I need to know how to get there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your identity

\begin{equation*}
\frac{3\pi ^{3}}{4}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{6(\pi ^{2}n^{2}-2)(-1)^{n}+12}{
\pi n^{4}}(-1)^{n}
\end{equation*}

expanding the right hand side and using the result $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{3\pi ^{4}}{4} &=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{6(\pi
^{2}n^{2}-2)(-1)^{n}+12}{n^{4}}(-1)^{n} \\
&=&6\pi ^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}-12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1
}{n^{4}}+12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{4}} \\
&=&\pi ^{4}-12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}-12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{4}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now *we need to express the alternating series* $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{
(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{4}}$ *in terms of* $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}$, e.g.
as follows

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{n^{4}} &=&\sum_{n=1}^{
\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n)^{4}}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}-\frac{1}{2^{3}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{1}{n^{4}}=\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{3\pi ^{4}}{4} &=&\pi ^{4}-12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}-\frac{
21}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}} \\
&=&\pi ^{4}-\frac{45}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Solving for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}$ we finally obtain

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{4}}=\frac{2}{45}\left( \pi ^{4}-\frac{3\pi
^{4}}{4}\right) =\frac{\pi ^{4}}{90}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: What a pure genius.  I haven't seen that type of derivation of the alternating series before.  Nice one.  It will be useful for my computation! :D

Comment: Many thanks. Glad to help. Google [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) or Alternating zeta function.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\pi x\cot\pars{\pi x}&=1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2x^{2} \over x^{2} - n^{2}}
=1 - 2x^{2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
- 2x^{4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}
- 2x^{6}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{6}} - \cdots
\end{align}

> $$
> \pi x^{1/2}\cot\pars{\pi x^{1/2}}=1 - 2x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
> - 2x^{2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}
> - 2x^{3}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{6}} - \cdots
> $$
>   For $\verts{z} \sim 0$:
>   \begin{align}
> z\cot\pars{z}&={z \over \tan\pars{z}} \sim {z \over z + z^{3}/3 + 2z^{5}/15}
> ={1 \over 1 + z^{2}/3 + 2z^{4}/15}
> \\[3mm]&\sim 1 - \pars{{z^{2} \over 3} + {2z^{4} \over 15}}
> + \pars{{z^{2} \over 3} + {2z^{4} \over 15}}^{2}
> \sim 1 - {z^{2} \over 3} - {2z^{4} \over 15} + {z^{4} \over 9}
> =1 - {z^{2} \over 3} - {z^{4} \over 45}
> \end{align}

$$
\pi x^{1/2}\cot\pars{\pi x^{1/2}}\sim
1 - {\pi^{2} \over 3}\,x - {\pi^{4} \over 45}\,x^{2}
$$

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}}
> = -\,\half\,\pars{-\,{\pi^{4} \over 45}}
> = \color{#00f}{\large{\pi^{4} \over 90}}
> $$